# TabLayout - No resource identifier found for attribute

Tags: android, material-design

I am using `TabLayout`  which is introduced in new android widget package `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`

Yesterday my code is working fine, now today I was start my computer and trying to re-build the project now Mr. Compiler is saying following error

```
Error:(22) No resource identifier found for attribute 'eleMode' in package 'android'
Error:(22) No resource identifier found for attribute 'tabGrvation' in package 'android.com.hsc.yatra'
Error:(22) No resource identifier found for attribute 'tabavity' in package 'android.com.hsc.yatra'
```

Please guide me where I'm incorrect ? So my compiler get happy and then compile the project.

Here is my XML where original error was occured

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/toolbar"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"-->
            <!--android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"-->
            <!--app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"-->
            <!--app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />-->
            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_searched_bus">

            </include>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:eleMode="fixed"
                app:tabGrvation="2dp"
                app:tabavity="fill" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add support library to your **build.gradle (Module:app)** as follows,

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:design:24.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are typos in the xml attributes. Change the attributes to the following and try.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Comment: Same error, you are also using `tabMode` & `tabGravity` these field is not recognized by compiler

Comment: What is  solution? can you please provide ?